# Delete ndb entity using the key.id()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the key id of the entity I want to delete, but when trying to delete using get_by_id, it is not deleting the entity (it's not doing anything).

The numerical id (I assume its a number, not a string) is stored in the 'key' get data:

```
d = car_database.Car()
ident = self.request.get('key')
d.get_by_id(ident).delete()
```

The id in this instance is: 5659313586569216

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.  Please look at the documentation on deleting entities - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#deleting_entities - it's pretty clear what you should be doing.

In your case you should be

```
ident = self.request.get('key')
d = car_database.Car.get_by_id(ident)
if d:
    d.key.delete()
```

Note that `get_by_id` is in fact a classmethod so you don't need to instantiate in instance of `Car` to use it.

And `delete` is a method of the `Key`, not of `Model`.

Comment: Use `long(ident)` to get the numerical value of the key

Comment: @brent washburne good point unless they id's are numerical strings ;-)